# Application Insights shows GET calls while my code does not have any such calls being made

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service

We have integrated Azure Application insights with our bot built using Azure bot framework using node.JS and typescript. Everything looks fine and we can see telemetry data flowing in.

In the failures section, we can see Operation name "GET /api/messages" showing repeated times - one failed call (405) and one success call (200).

But we have no GET operation being done on "/api/messages" in our code. We only have "POST" operations.

We are unable to understand why telemetry shows GET operation and one as failed and one as success.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything stored in the `operation_SyntheticSource` field of the request telemetry

Comment: Are you looking at Requests (incoming calls) or Dependencies (outgoing calls)?

Comment: I didn't find any doc mentioned your weird problem, I think you may offer more details on app insights failure information and related code to help troubleshot. And how did you integrate app insights in your program, writing code or codeless configuration?

Comment: @PeterBons: Yes, operationSyntheticSource column shows multiple values. Please advise what do they mean and how do we relate these to GET related calls ?

Comment: By inspecting the values you can sometimes determine the exact cause. Try running a query like `request | where operation_SyntheticSource != ""` and post the results in your question. We might pinpoint the origin.

Comment: @PeterBons: Just added sample records where operation_SyntheticSource column is NULL. Please review and advise. All GET operation messages have this column as NULL. And every time, it shows 2 lines - one failed and one Success.

Comment: if operation_SyntheticSource column is NULL it is not traffic that is generated by the infrastructure. Not sure where it comes from

Comment: @PeterBons. Of. I will try to post this to Microsoft App Insights community

Answer (score 3):

The `operation_SyntheticSource` field of request telemetry is often used by microsoft / azure to indicate traffic that is generated by infrastructure or bots. Examples are health requests, keep alive traffic, spider bots.

There are options to filter out telemetry, so it is possible to filter out telemetry cause by synthetic traffic. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#example-filters).

Telemetry processors can be configured using [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#wiring-up-telemetry-in-your-bot).